# Android retrofit - date format when passing datetime by URL

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2, date-format

I have API method mapping like this

```
@POST("api/updateStarted/{id}/{started}")
suspend fun updateStarted(
    @Path("id") id: Int,
    @Path("started") started: Date
) : Response <Int>
```

I want to use `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` format everywhere. My API adapter looks like this:

```
val gson = GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")

val apiClient: ApiClient = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson.create()))
    .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
    .client(getHttpClient(API_USERNAME, API_PASSWORD))
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build()
    .create(ApiClient::class.java)
```

However `GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")` cannot affect date format when I pass it thru URL (because that's not JSON) so Retrofit builds URL like this:

```
http://myserver.com/api/updateFinished/2/Fri%20Jan%2027%2013:48:42%20GMT+01:00%202023
```

instead of something like this:

```
http://myserver.com/api/updateFinished/2/2023-01-28T02:03:04.000
```

How can I fix that? I'm new in Retrofit and I don't fully understand date/time libraries in Java.

Comment: unrelated: you're adding GsonConverterFactory twice

Comment: You seem to be getting the `toString()` of a `java.util.Date`, you can either use a `SimpleDateFormat` in order to format that date or, better, don't use a `Date` and switch to `java.time`. Looks like you want a `java.time.LocalDateTime` (no zone or offset).

Comment: @deHaar Thanks. It is working now. Why did you write in a comment and not as an answer?

Comment: What exactly did you do? Did you use a `SimpleDateFormat` along with a fitting pattern or did you use a `LocalDateTime`? Just suggesting to use another data type is not really worth an answer here on SO.

Comment: @deHaar I just changed `@Path("started") started: Date` to `@Path("started") started: LocalDateTime` and to call this method I have to pass `LocalDateTime.now()` instead of `Date.from(Instant.now())`

Comment: OK, good… I made an answer from it, but the other answer looks promising, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch the data type from `java.util.Date` to `java.time.LocalDateTime` if you want your desired format using the `toString()` method of that data type.

Currently, you have `Date.toString()` producing an undesired result.

If you don't have to use a `Date`, `import java.time.LocalDateTime` and just change your `fun` a little to this:

```kotlin
@POST("api/updateStarted/{id}/{started}")
suspend fun updateStarted(
    @Path("id") id: Int,
    @Path("started") started: LocalDateTime
) : Response <Int>
```

Answer (score 1):

`GsonConverterFactory` supports `responseBodyConverter` and `requestBodyConverter` which aren't used to convert URL params. For that, you need a `stringConverter` which, fortunately is trivial to implement:

```
class MyToStringConverter : Converter<SomeClass, String> {
    override fun convert(value: SomeClass): String {
        return formatToMyDesiredUrlParamFormat(value)
    }

    companion object {
        val INSTANCE = MyToStringConverter()
    }
}

class MyConverterFactory : Converter.Factory() {
    override fun stringConverter(type: Type, annotations: Array<out Annotation>, retrofit: Retrofit): Converter<*, String>? {
        return if (type == SomeClass::class.java) {
            //extra check to make sure the circumstances are correct:
            if (annotations.any { it is retrofit2.http.Query }) {
                MyToStringConverter.INSTANCE
            } else {
                null
            }
        } else {
            null
        }
    }
}
```

and then

```
val apiClient: ApiClient = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
    .client(getHttpClient(API_USERNAME, API_PASSWORD))
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .addConverterFactory(MyConverterFactory())
    //(...)
```

I've added checking for annotations as example if one would want tighter control on when the converter is used.

Comment: I have solved my problem by changing data type, but thats pretty useful. Could you please add information how can I use or add that converter to my ApiClient?

Comment: @Kamil You're already adding other converter factory (the gson one), but I've added example for clarity. Keep in mind that converters registered first take priority. `stringConverter` doesn't clash with `GsonConverterFactory` but ordering matters with more converters.